# Verificar se o email preenchido já existe no banco de dados em "TEMPO REAL"

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um formulário para cadastro, mas preciso que ao preencher o campo e-mail, quando a pessoa passa para o próximo campo, ele busque no banco de dados e retorne uma mensagem avisando se já estiver este e-mail cadastrado no banco de dados. Conforme algumas perguntas que eu encontrei aqui e em outros lugares, cheguei nesse metodo:

**register.php** - Aqui esta trecho JS e a INPUT

```
<script language="javascript">
    var email = $("#email"); 
        email.blur(function() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'verificaEmail.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
                data:{"email" : email.val()}, 
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                data = $.parseJSON(data); 
                $("#resposta").text(data.email);
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>

<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" required>
<div id="resposta"></div>
```

**verificaEmail.php**

```
<?php
#Verifica se tem um email para pesquisa
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ 

    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $emailPostado = $_POST['email'];

    #Conecta banco de dados 
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "academia");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Email = '{$emailPostado}'") or print mysql_error();

    #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Ja existe um usuario cadastrado com este email')); 
    else 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Usuário valido.' )); 
}
?>
```

Mas ele não esta funcionando. Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver isso, como não intendo muito de jQuery e PHP, estou sofrendo um pouco nisso. Não sei se é necessário, mas aqui esta o PHP para cadastrar que esta no ACTION do FORM.

```
<?php

/* substitua as variáveis abaixo pelas que se adequam ao seu caso */
$dbhost = 'localhost'; // endereco do servidor de banco de dados
$dbuser = 'root'; // login do banco de dados
$dbpass = ''; // senha
$dbname = 'academia'; // nome do banco de dados a ser usado

$conecta = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$seleciona = mysqli_select_db($conecta, $dbname);

$nome       = $_POST ["nome"];  
$sobrenome  = $_POST ["sobrenome"];
$email      = $_POST ["email"];
$senha      = $_POST ["senha"];
$telefone   = $_POST ["telefone"];
$ddd        = $_POST ["ddd"];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO usuarios (ID, Nome, Sobrenome, Email, Senha, Telefone, DDD) VALUES (DEFAULT, '$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha', '$telefone', '$ddd')";
$inserenome = mysqli_query( $conecta, $sqlinsert );

// inicia a conexao ao servidor de banco de dados
if(! $conecta )
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel conectar: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "<br />Conexao realizada!";

// seleciona o banco de dados no qual a tabela vai ser criada
if (! $seleciona)
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel selecionar o banco de dados $dbname");
}
echo "<br />Selecionado o banco de dados $dbname";

// finalmente, cria a tabela 
if(! $inserenome )
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel inserir registro: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "<br />Um novo registro foi feito!";
// encerra a conexão
mysqli_close($conecta);

?>
```

Haa, e o email esta como UNIQUE no MYSQL, por isso quando n tinha esse JS e o verificaEmail, quando eu tentava cadastrar um email ja existente, ele simplesmente n cadastrava e mostrada o "Nao foi possivel inserir registro:"

Comment: Pode ser porque seu script está sendo executado antes do elemento `#email` ter sido inserido no [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction). Tente colocar seu script depois do elemento `#resposta`.

Comment: Blz, deu certo, agora só que mesmo eu colocando algum email que ja esta cadastrado, ele diz que ja existe e tudo mais, só que ele cadastra igual.

Comment: Exemplo, no meu campo repita a senha:
<input name="senha_confirma" type="password" value="" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" required oninput="validaSenha(this)">
Tenho esse script que enquanto nao estiver da maneira correta, nao deixa enviar o formulario:
function validaSenha (input){ 
 if (input.value != document.getElementById('txtSenha').value) {
    input.setCustomValidity('As senhas não coecidem!');
  } else {
    input.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

Comment: Parece que agora você precisa bloquear o envio quando o campo `#email` for inválido. Você pode usa o próprio `setCustomValidity` no campo `#email`, dentro da função de `success` da sua requisição. Sugiro que abra outra questão pra resolver seu novo problema, uma vez que a questão ***Verificar se o email preenchido já existe no banco de dados em “TEMPO REAL”*** foi aparentemente resolvida.

Comment: Boa noite. Peço que me coriga caso eu esteja errado. Pela sua logica você confere se o email esta cadastrado no banco de dados assim que o usuário sai do campo mas assim que o php do form e acionado a um comando de insert sem nenhuma condição antes dele. Neste caso você teria que verificar novamente se o email já esta cadastrado no banco de dados caso esteja você retorna o usuário para a pagina e pede para conferir o email, caso contrario use o comando select para inserir as informações.